# 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. error when running PHP shell_exec

Tags: python, php

I'm running this code via PHP file.

```
<?php 
echo shell_exec('python C:/wamp64/www/registration/test.py 2>&1');
?>
```

I'm getting this error,

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file

I have added path variable correctly and when I run python in command line starts python console. I'm not familier with python so great if someone can help. (I'm using windows 10 and wamp server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put full path, like this:

```
    echo shell_exec('C:/python27/python.exe C:/wamp64/www/registration/test.py 2>&1');
```

Just replace it with your path

Comment: Thanks and I have "C:/Python/Python392" but no python.exe there

Comment: Then try to locate your python.exe, there must be one in order for python to work.

Comment: @GithmiKalupahana - You need to find out where the python executable is located and add that path.

Comment: Got my python.exe in another location thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to solve this

1. Add python path to your system $PATH, which make you can call python from any directory (including the one the shell_exec is using) then you can simply do `shell_exec('python C:/wamp64/www/registration/test.py 2>&1');`
2. Use your python path in the command as @ivan-gajic mentionned `shell_exec('{python_full_path}/python C:/wamp64/www/registration/test.py 2>&1');`

since you said you already added python to the PATH and it's not working, it means you added it to a specific user PATH, try adding it to the system PATH which make python accessible for every user directly

Comment: They already say _"I have added path variable correctly"_ which means tht athe first suggestion won't work for them. Most likely it is because they are calling the PHP page through a web server. Web servers are usually running as a different user, while the path variable is user specific.

Comment: it's because he maybe added it to a user PATH, and not the global system PATH, which will make python accessible directly to any user without typing the whole python directory path

Comment: You should explain that distinction more clearly in your answer.

Comment: yes, i updated the answer to be better, thanks to you ;)